# Handling Python IndexError from regressor_OLS.pvalues

Tags: python, regression, p-value, index-error

I want to reduce the number of features of a sparse matrix as below, but after passing a range I get an IndexError. It seems that after 2, access to `regressor_OLS.pvalues` is not possible because the `print` command also leads to the same error. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

def backwardElimination(x, Y, sl, columns):
    numVars = len(x[0])
    pvalue_removal_counter = 0

    for i in range(0, numVars):
        print(i, 'of', numVars)
        regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(Y, x).fit()
        maxVar = max(regressor_OLS.pvalues).astype(float)

        if maxVar > sl:  # sl = 0.05
            for j in range(0, numVars - i):
                # print (regressor_OLS.pvalues)
                if (regressor_OLS.pvalues[j].astype(float) == maxVar):
                    x = np.delete(x, j, 1)
                    pvalue_removal_counter += 1
                    columns = np.delete(columns, j)

    regressor_OLS.summary()
    return x, columns
```

Output:

```
0 of 1970
1 of 1970
2 of 1970
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 142, in <module>
    selected_columns)
  File "main.py", line 101, in backwardElimination
    if (regressor_OLS.pvalues[j].astype(float) == maxVar):
IndexError: index 1967 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1967
```